# Tomcat IOException: Duplicate accept detected. This is a known OS bug. Please consider reporting that you are affected:

Tags: spring-boot, ubuntu, tomcat

I just migrated to a new spring boot version lately, namely v2.6.2 and now I find the following exception of some of the services logs.

```
23:27:45.148 [main] INFO  o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (https) with context path ''
23:27:47.046 [main] INFO  o.a.c.i.engine.AbstractCamelContext - Routes startup (total:1 started:1)
23:27:47.048 [main] INFO  o.a.c.i.engine.AbstractCamelContext -     Started route1 (jms://queue:inp.contentextractor.entry)
23:27:47.049 [main] INFO  o.a.c.i.engine.AbstractCamelContext - Apache Camel 3.14.0 (camel-1) started in 2s228ms (build:622ms init:1s32ms start:574ms)
23:27:47.061 [main] INFO  eu.hermes.esb.cloud.Application - Started Application in 25.305 seconds (JVM running for 27.737)
23:28:20.356 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-4] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
23:28:20.357 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-4] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
23:28:20.359 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-4] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed initialization in 2 ms
00:05:19.986 [https-jsse-nio-8080-Acceptor] ERROR org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Acceptor - Socket accept failed
java.io.IOException: Duplicate accept detected. This is a known OS bug. Please consider reporting that you are affected: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1924298 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.serverSocketAccept(NioEndpoint.java:545)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.serverSocketAccept(NioEndpoint.java:78)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Acceptor.run(Acceptor.java:129)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
05:20:49.981 [https-jsse-nio-8080-Acceptor] ERROR org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Acceptor - Socket accept failed
java.io.IOException: Duplicate accept detected. This is a known OS bug. Please consider reporting that you are affected: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1924298 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.serverSocketAccept(NioEndpoint.java:545)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.serverSocketAccept(NioEndpoint.java:78)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Acceptor.run(Acceptor.java:129)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

What does it mean and how harmful is it ?

Comment: We're in the same boat :( We recently upgraded from Spring Boot "1.5.9.RELEASE" to "2.6.2" and now we're seeing this under load-tests.

Comment: From what I've read online, this is a bug with Linux. But that fact that it wasn't happening on the same OS but with an older build of Spring Boot makes it seem like a Spring Boot bug. Unless the new Spring Boot version is just using newer OS calls that have the bug... either way, does anyone know the latest version of Spring Boot is not affected by this?

Comment: Same here. Under 2.5.6 we are not seeing this issue, in 2.5.8 and 2.5.9 however the problem exists.

Comment: From what I've read, it has to do with the version of Tomcat. Overriding the "tomcat.version" to "9.0.58" seems to fix the issue. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26434#issuecomment-1047599788

Answer (score 1):

Following the link provided in the bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1924298), and looking into comments made by community members, it seems that there is something in tomcat usage that uncovered a hidden issue in linux kernal 5.10-rc4 and was most likely fixed in 5.10-rc6.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1924298/comments/15

This issue was reported across centOS, amazon linux, Arch linux and even Window 2019 - when using a lower linux kernel than 5.10.

The conclusion from this discussion seems to be the suggestion to update the OS itself to a stable version that uses linux kernel >= 5.10

Answer (score 1):

We also ran into this.

We also used Spring Boot version 2.6.2 in our application. We encountered the error after upgrading the version of our k8s-cluster, including an OS and Kernel update of the cluster nodes.

So far we verified that the error only occurs on nodes with a kernel higher than `5.4.0-121-generic`. Also tested on the latest kernel version `5.15.0-57-generic`, where we still got the error.

We than updated our services to Spring Boot `2.7.8`. Now everything works fine as the error message don't show up anymore.